# Can we host ASP.NET Core application on linux without Kestrel?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using .Net core 2.2.
I want to host it in linux say Centos 7.
I am ok to use Apache or nginx etc as hosting server but do not want to use them in reverse configuration with kestrel. That means i do not want to use Kestrel in pipeline at all.
Is this possible and how?

Comment: This document should tell you everything you need (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x)

Comment: @sachin soni, Not 100% sure but may be not because `Kestrel` is the cross platform server for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Excluding kerstel and using Apachae/nginx as base server may not be possible. You will have to write your own server implementation based on OWIN and get that communicated with apache/nginx .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=linux